# Python Tkinter Button Command Resetting Variables

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I am trying to code a Tic-Tac-Toe game. I am trying to update values after a button is pressed. The updates are not sticking and are reset after every button press. I am absolutely stumped and I am a beginner so please explain to me why I need to have to declare turn as global in the main() method as well as my on_click method.

Also a brief explanation on why the lambda: inx=count: on_click(inx) works but lambda: on_click(count) will not work.

Any tips to help this code work better or make more sense would be fantastic. I am not used to using classes either which is why it is all functions. Not sure where or when to use classes quite yet.

I have tried just about everything I can think of to fix this issue but I cannot figure it out.

```
    import tkinter


    def on_click(inx):
        buttonfont = ('helvetica', 100, 'bold')
        global turn
        turn += 1
        spot = {}

        if turn % 2 == 0:
            buttons[inx].configure(text='O', width=200, height=200, compound='center', state='disabled', font=buttonfont, disabledforeground='blue')
            spot.update({inx: 'O'})
        else:
            buttons[inx].configure(text='X', width=200, height=200, compound='center', state='disabled', font=buttonfont, disabledforeground='red')
            spot.update({inx: 'X'})


    def create_window_and_buttons():
        game_window = tkinter.Tk()
        game_window.title('Tic-Tac-Toe')
        for i in range(0, 3):
            game_window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
            game_window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        game_window.geometry('600x600')
        global pixel
        pixel = tkinter.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
        count = 0
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                buttons.append(tkinter.Button(game_window, image=pixel, width=200, height=200, command=lambda inx=count:
                                              on_click(inx)))
                buttons[count].grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='NSEW')
                count += 1

        return game_window


    def main():
        global turn
        turn = 0
        global buttons
        buttons = []
        game_window = create_window_and_buttons()
        game_window.mainloop()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I expected to have it update the dictionary and then continue to add values but instead, it resets every time. Also had the same problem with the turn variable before setting it as global in both main() and on_click().

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting your `spot` dict every time you execute `on_click`. Just move it outside to the main function:

```
import tkinter

spot = {}

def on_click(inx):
   buttonfont = ('helvetica', 100, 'bold')
   global turn
   turn += 1
   #spot = {}
   ...
```

And on why `lambda: on_click(count)` does not work as you intend it to, this is due to Python's closure being late binding and you can read it up [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures).